# Using more than one argument to 'apply' in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series(['1a', '2a'])
b = pd.Series(['1b', '2b'])
c = pd.Series([2, 3])

df = pd.concat((a.rename('a'), b.rename('b'), c.rename('c')), axis=1)

def ar(a, b, c):
    arr = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(np.arange(c)))
    arr['a'] = a
    arr['b'] = b

    return arr
```

How can apply method be used to generate:

> ```
> a     b   0   1   2
> ---------------------
> 1a    1b  0   0   NaN
> 1a    1b  0   1   NaN
> 2a    2b  0   0   0
> 2a    2b  0   1   0
> 2a    2b  0   0   1
> ```

...something like `df.c.apply(ar, df.a, df.b)` does not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick and simple way is to "vectorize" your function by using `np.vectorize`, allowing numpy to "hide" the loop (a lot like `apply`, but with less overhead).

```
v = np.vectorize(ar)
pd.concat(v(df.a, df.b, df.c))

   0  1   a   b    2
0  0  0  1a  1b  NaN
1  0  1  1a  1b  NaN
0  0  0  2a  2b  0.0
1  0  1  2a  2b  0.0
2  0  0  2a  2b  2.0
```

`vectorize` takes as input, a function that operates on scalars, and allows you to pass vectors which are operated upon element-wise.

This is similar to looping over a `zip`ped version of your input and calling `ar` at each iteration -

```
r = []
for x, y, z in zip(df.a, df.b, df.c):
    r.append(ar(x, y, z))

pd.concat(r)

   0  1   a   b    2
0  0  0  1a  1b  NaN
1  0  1  1a  1b  NaN
0  0  0  2a  2b  0.0
1  0  1  2a  2b  0.0
2  0  0  2a  2b  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `map` function here which is very similar to `apply` for dataframes:

```
outlist = list(map(lambda x,y,z: ar(x,y,z), a,b,c))
outdf = pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, outlist))) 
# or: outdf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(out[0]), pd.DataFrame(out[1])])
print(outdf)
```

Output:

```
   0  1   a   b    2
0  0  0  1a  1b  NaN
1  0  1  1a  1b  NaN
0  0  0  2a  2b  0.0
1  0  1  2a  2b  0.0
2  0  0  2a  2b  2.0
```

Comment: map looks to be equally fast as np.vectorize

Comment: map is a very useful, general purpose, higher-order function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)